# Laravel - How to efficiently apply Eloquent ORM in getting data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new with Laravel, and I am creating a booking system with it. Now I want to ask  if there's a shorter way / correct way on how to get a data from the DB using Eloquent. I need to display data from a series of select for the selection of rooms .[(screenshot- I will hide the other select using jQuery based on the selected option on the first 2 drop downs. I don't want to use AJAX for this)](http://prntscr.com/mabk27).

Now what I'm doing is I am passing different arrays from controller to blade:

```
$rooms = Room::where('Availability',0)->get();
$room_types = Room::distinct()->select('RoomType')->get();
$floor_nos = Room::distinct()->select('FloorNo')->get();
```

But I don't know how will I group them based on the room types and floor nos:
Here's my data:

```
Room Type - Bedspace
Floor No - 1
Room Nos [BS201, BS202, BS203, BS301,BS302,BS303, FR201, FR301(3rd Floor Family Rooms)]
Each Room No has Bed Nos. [BS201(1-UPPER, 2-UPPER),BS202(1-UPPER,2-UPPER)]
```

I need to show this:

```
First dropdown - Room Types
Second dropdown - Floor Nos
Third dropdown - Room Nos
Fourth dropdown - Bed Nos
```

So when I select Room Type Bedspace, and Floor No 2, The third select dropdown would be `BS201, BS202, BS203`. And if I select Family Room, and Floor No 3, the third select drop down would be `FR201`, then if I select `FR201`, the Bed No should be `1-UPPER` (the value here would be the ID of that bed no)

EDIT: Screenshot of my rooms table: http://prntscr.com/mac4o9

Comment: Hi Paul. Are we able to see the structure of your `rooms` table? Also, if you want to have the dropdowns auto-load the correct subgroups then you'll either need to do some sort of page refresh, or use javascript to change subsequent dropdowns based on the user input, either via ajax or by sending all the data to the page and then using js to filter it.

Comment: Sure, I will edit my post. That's what I am planning, I will add data-* attributes to the options to filter using js.

Comment: Was there any specific reason that this is all in one table, rather than having related tables? I don't think it'll make much difference, just wondering.

Comment: Re-reading your question, what specific problem are we solving here?

Comment: I need to have a series of drop downs that are connected to each other, I mean how will I perform the retrieving of data efficiently http://prntscr.com/macbt4 , my problem is that I cannot separate Room Nos for Family Room and Bedspace Rooms they are combined based on their floor nos. Regarding the table, you mean I should have a separate table for room type, floors etc? I just need to connect the room to a check in. Im sorry I am really new with Laravel and DB creation.

Comment: Do you want to do this all in PHP, and have the page refresh each time? Or would you want it to be seamless, and be willing to programme in javascript?

Comment: What I'm planning is for the first page load, it will create several selects like the screenshot above, then I will add javascript to hide the other select. And will add onchange action on select.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187088/discussion-between-kurucu-and-paul-john-pulumbarit).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create three Dropdown

1. Available Rooms
2. On Selection run one Ajax and get Option for Room Type
3. On selection Room type Run ajax and get option for Foor No

for Ajax you can use below code

```
jQuery( ajax {
     url: '{!! route('frontend.get-room-types') !!}',
     method: 'POST',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     data: {
         selectedRoom: document.getElementById("selectedRoom").value
     },
     success: function(data)
     {
         //Set Options for Room Type.
     },
     error: function(data)
     {
        alert("Something went Wrong");
     }

})
```

In that way you can get Latest Data by Ajax call.